# Why one method of reading string in C using char* pointer works while other doesn't?

Tags: c, pointers, dangling-pointer

I am reading a string in C using the pointers, through the following two methods, both are exactly same(at least they appear to me). The only difference is in one method I have made a dedicated function to do the job.

**Method 1:** // Works as expected

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str;
    char delimiter='.';
    int len=0;
    
    scanf("%c",(str+len));
    while(*(str+len)!=delimiter)
    {   
        ++len;
        scanf("%c",(str+len));
    }
    ++len;
    *(str+len)='\0';

    printf("%s",str);

    return 0;
}
```

**Method 2:** // Doesn't work, nothing gets printed on the screen

```
#include <stdio.h>

int readString(char *str,char delimiter)
{
    int len=0;
    
    scanf("%c",(str+len));
    while(*(str+len)!=delimiter)
    {   
        ++len;
        scanf("%c",(str+len));
    }
    ++len;
    *(str+len)='\0';

    return len;
}

int main()
{
    char *str;
    
    int len=readString(str,'.');

    printf("%s",str);

    return 0;
}
```

I am completely clueless about what I am doing wrong.

While further playing with the code in Method 2, I observed if I just declare a variable(even useless) with initialisation(like `int useless=-1;`) between lines `char *str;` and `int len=readString(str,'.');` the code works fine.

This added further to my headache.

**Can someone explain what is really going on?**

My guess is it has to do something with dangling pointers, but then if that was the case Method 1 should have also failed.

Comment: Just declare your string `str` with square brackets like so `char str[100]` or any buffer size you like. This way you are making room for your string to be stored. When you just use a pointer you don't have memory set aside for your string and you can only point to the memory location where your string is stored using a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first code

```
 scanf("%c",(str+len));
```

you're trying to write into (access) a memory location which is invalid. Notice that `str` actually is uninitialized, i.e., it does not point to any valid memory location. So, the program invokes **[undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** and the outcome cannot be justified in any way.

In the second code, the same problem is present, so the behaviour is undefined again.